# Using photos without permission for purpose of charity

Tags: copyright

I'm making a video collage of photos from the internet of the California wildfires to ask for people's donations for the first responders. Will I run afoul with copyright laws in doing this, or will this be ok under a 'fair use' case, as I am not looking to profit, but rather collect donations for charity.

Answer (score 3):

Collecting donations **is** profiting. Merely because those profits will be used in order to help someone/thing it doesn't change the fact that usage of the images would be benefiting an organization.

There's *no such thing* as "altruistic usage" which circumvent copyright infringements.

"Profit" in terms of unauthorized image use equates to *any* use which provides value. "Fair Use" refers to usage where *nothing* is directly gained from the use.

It certainly sounds to me as though the usage you describe would be unauthorized use and an infringement.

Charities, non-profits, and/or not-for profit organizations do *not* get "free reign" to use anything merely due to the nature of their business. They are bound to copyright laws the same as *any* other organization.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will refrain from creating a visual platform for the cause then.

Comment: While it would be unauthorized use.. in many cases the odds of someone actually pursuing legal matters for such a cause would be slim. Not impossible, but most wouldn't want to be the "copyright holder not supporting first responders". Still, you should be aware there is possible liability.

Comment: OFFTOPIC: Better make a poster for a new president man, because this one is shaking hands with business, not the planet. How much ***** growth do we really need ?!